# How to count how many posts each link has on a reddit-like app?

Tags: python, django

I have a reddit-like website where users post links and those links can be commented on. I want to display the number of comments under each link before being taken to the comment page for that link. What is the most query efficient way to do this in django that doesn't slow down the rendering of my site? I assume I'll have to go through a for loop of each link on the page to count the number of posts for each one and populate a list of some sort with the number returned from the .count() of each queryset? Here's what I have:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    newlinktag = models.ForeignKey('NewLink', null=False) 
    childtag = models.ForeignKey('Post', blank=True, null=True)
    postcontent = models.CharField(max_length=1024) 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.postcontent


class NewLink(models.Model):
    posttag = models.ForeignKey('PageInfo') #the page each link belongs to
    linkcomment = models.CharField(max_length=512) 
    postlinkdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #submission datestamp.
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 1024) 
    linkowner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jape gave you a good answer, but it is always more efficient to preform counting in the database rather than in python loops.

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count

def view(request):
    # Calculate the counts at the same time we fetch the NewLink(s)
    links = NewLink.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('post_set'))
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'links': links})
```

**html**

```
{% for link in links %}
    {{ link.post_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model, I would create a `cached_property` and then when you run the `for loop` in your template, call the property to get the count.

For example,

**models.py:**

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
    posttag = models.ForeignKey('PageInfo') #the page each link belongs to
    linkcomment = models.CharField(max_length=512) 
    postlinkdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #submission datestamp.
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 1024) 
    linkowner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    # Might also want to flush this after a post_save method in your signals
    @cached_property
    def linkcomment_count(self):
        return self.linkcomment.count()
```

**views.py:**

```
def view(request):
    # Could do a 'select_related' relationship to save hits on the database
    comments = NewLink.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'comments': comments})
```

**html:**

```
{% for link in comments %}
    {{ link.linkcomment_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Did I understand your question correctly?